# How to setup custom subdomain with Posterous blog

Tags: domain, subdomain, cname-record, url

I want to setup my custom subdomain with my posterous blog: tahirakram.posterous.com.

I am confused over setting up A record and CNAME.

Do I need to set A record and CNAME both to run my posterous to this URL: blog.tahirakram.com?

So far I set up CNAME 
Name: blog.tahirakram.com 
Value: posterous.com

Should I set A recrod name value too? (if yes, as following)
Host Name: blog.tahirakram.com
Destination IPv4 Address: 67.207.139.81

[Instruction](http://posterous.com/help/custom_domain) given by posterous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow this guide http://posterous.com/help/custom_domain ? A record was all I added. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks Khanh Le, I need to add A record for blog.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0):

No, the CNAME record is enough. Depending on the tool you use to edit the DNS-records you might have to set the value to posterous.com. (with a trailing .) to make it an absolute name.

Comment: tliff; No luck. When I place a . at the end of posterous.com in value field of CNAME. It does not saved. I mean . at the end is not getting appended.